# What happens in memory when an application is crashed or killed by an operating system

Tags: c, debugging, memory

For my research purposes, I want to see what changes are made by an operating system when a program is killed/crashed due to some error, say buffer overflow attack.

Let me explain the whole scenario here.

Suppose an application is running and its data and code is in memory. An attacker tries to hijack the application by exploiting some buffer overflow vulnerability to get access to the machine but system detects it and kills that application which is being exploited. Now I want to see if there are any traces left behind by the operating system in the memory when it killed the process and what necessary steps OS took before killing that process.

Also, is there any tool which can take track memory changes live when a c program is executing? and can we decompile memory snapshot data to some human readable language (assembly code, may be)?

Edit::

For following example

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>


int main()
{

int x;
char arr[4];
char * src = "haha";

printf("Before copying\n");

scanf("%d", &x);
if(x> 1)
    strcpy(arr, src);
printf("%s \n", arr);
return 0;
}
```

It is producing buffer overflow error. Before check, it works fine. After giving input of x greater than 1, it crashes the program. I want to see if there are any traces left behind in the memory even if this program is crashed/killed.

Thanks.

Comment: I know of no operating system that can detect an attack and kill a processes. On a linux system you can use gcore to take a live snapshot of the process which can be examined by gdb. Which OS are you talking about?

Comment: Stack smashing protectors cause programs to suicide when they detect buffer overflows, which is what I think @Junaid meant.

Comment: Well, I thought, Windows (or Intrusion Detection Systems) work like this. I mean, when they are successful to detect which application is trying to use unallocated memory (memory violation rule), Windows kill the process and gives option like 'Abort', 'Debug' and 'Cancel'. Please see the example above I am going to post in five minutes.

Comment: @AdrianCornish The OS can deny servicing specific system calls to the callers residing in memory sections that aren't supposed to contain code or to be executable. So, if some maliciously crafted data runs away as code, that can be detected sometimes. The OS, though, wouldn't really know if that's a real attack or just a program bug. It can terminate the process without much grief in such an odd, but potentially harmful case.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze Can you name an OS that does this so I can read about it

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze: You are partially correct. What you are referring to is called no-execute. It is a way of marking memory regions as non-executable; if the program attempts to execute from a non-executable region, it will be treated as a fatal program error (see my answer). All major OSes support no-execute behaviour (e.g. NX bit, `mprotect(~PROT_EXEC)`, non-executable stack, etc.). This prevents malicious programs from placing executable code on e.g. the stack, but doesn't preclude things like return-oriented programming or *return-to-libc* attacks.

Answer (score 5):

OSes don't generally detect buffer overflows or other malicious attacks in progress unless the attack causes a fatal error in the program (e.g. causing it to access bad memory or jump to an invalid address). In that case, the OS will handle the situation like any other process error: on Windows, the structured exception handling (SEH) mechanism is invoked to unwind the process stack (which may result in an "unhandled exception" dialog); on UNIX-like systems, the OS sends the process a (normally fatal) signal which the process can catch.

Some applications are compiled with stack smashing protectors or other protection features which automatically `abort()` the application (or otherwise exit) if the stack becomes corrupt (indicative of a programming error or exploited buffer overflow). In this case, it is the application itself that attempts to terminate. Normally, these mechanisms use a termination method that exits the application as fast as possible, to minimize the chance that they can be disabled.

In either case, if we assume the process dies, then the OS marks the process as dead and stops giving it any CPU cycles. The process may remain as a "zombie" so that its parent can determine its exit code (on UNIX), but the memory it formerly used will be released back to the OS. The OS may then give the freed memory to other processes. Some systems and configurations will perform a *core dump* of the process before it is cleaned up if it exits abnormally; the core dump contains the contents of the process memory before it was killed, and permits a developer to determine the cause of the error which triggered the exit.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there are any systems that can detect an attack and decide to kill the application being victimized.  What happens is that as a result of the attack, the program damages itself and becomes un-runable.  At that point, the operating system terminates it.

The metaphor of "attack" is misleading, as there is no force involved.  It's like you throw up because you ate too much, but nobody made you keep eating.

Sometimes when programs are terminated unexpectedly, the last state of the program is saved and can be analyzed, but not routinely.

Comment: Some attacks can be detected, others not. It depends a lot on the circumstances.

Comment: Please explain how exactly you can detect an attack and differentiate it from a programmer's bug.

Comment: In general, you can't.  A successful attack might be completely undetectable.  Someone deliberated feeding a program data that causes it to crash might be doing so perfectly innocently.